# WebKitErrorFrameLoadInterruptedByPolicyChange what is that?

Tags: iphone, facebook

I get **WebKitErrorFrameLoadInterruptedByPolicyChange** in

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error

using FBDialog when trying to share an URL for the first time in 
all next try are OK.

Do you have an idea why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you receive **WebKitErrorFrameLoadInterruptedByPolicyChange**?

There is a problem with SSO in Facebook connect. When an application become active after giving authorization in Safari or Facebook App, web view fails to load your initial share request.

I receive **Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999**. You can change if statement in (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error as follow to fix it:

```
if (!(([error.domain isEqualToString:@"NSURLErrorDomain"] && error.code == -999) ||
      !([error.domain isEqualToString:@"WebKitErrorDomain"] && error.code == 102))) {
    [self dismissWithError:error animated:YES];
}
```

https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/issues/56

Comment: this page gives a 404. I found a solutions at https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/issues/56